# Edit Ribbon only partially displaying

Tags: 2013, css, page-layout, ribbon

I have recently started customizing my SharePoint 2013 environment and everything seemed to be fine up until I decided to edit a page using Edit Page option from the cogwheel. The ribbon, when in edit page mode, does not display correctly. I can only see half of it. When I look though the master page, css files, etc. Everything is normal.I have tried retracing my steps but nothing seems to be working.

[image: ribbon not displaying]

Here is what it currently looks like. It looks like it has just been cut off.

I hope there is a setting I have overlooked. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Use F12 developer tool in your browser to see what's going on.

Comment: more info please? I have found the elements and have tracked them down in my solution

Comment: Well, im not a designer but i would open a ootb sharepoint site and compare my custom css with the original css..

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried that. I've looked at the Elements that pertain to the edit ribbon and I've seen that they are all still ootb. Nothing there has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your using custom CSS in your site, which is why you have a weird behavior, use developer tools in your browser and track what custom css might be causing it. Try to remove snippets of your custom CSS and see what was making it behave that way. You might not know it by now, but your CSS might be breaking other areas in the site you haven't seen yet.

Comment: I have been doing that. Do you have any helpful tips? I have found out that DeltaSPRibbon and RibbonContainer are responsibale for displaying that Edit Ribbon, but I cannot find any reason that it's not showing right. Those elements are not changed

Comment: I don't think you will find the CSS that's changing this behavior on these controls. It has something to do with the page's width itself. Try to select your whole page with the developer tools, and remove the CSS that's affecting the page's width, and see which one is responsible for that.

Comment: Why would the page width be doing that? the rest of the page displays normally

Comment: turns out ms-cui-tabBody was responsible. I removed all styling belonging to that class and it's back to normal